# OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) Parameter error: You cannot send messages to this id"

Tags: c#, api, facebook-graph-api, post

how to resolve

"Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) Parameter error: You cannot send messages to this id"

Do you have any idea ??

I try send a POST using NET and the parameters is

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{my_page}/messages?access_token={my acces token}
and body request I set a message text and recipient id in Json form

the id I get for app in the web, is id of a friend but An interaction was already made

What is missing ?

Comment: Hey, I'm having the exact same problem. Found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#100) Parameter error: You cannot send messages to this id"

I guess if the ID is the number in the url: https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100010603771535 <--- thos one, or I need another that is not just here...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the PSID and not the "default/normal" ID of the user.
PSID can be retrieved from messenger extensions (I don't know if it can be retrieved from Graph API without connecting the bot - please, answer in the comments).

Check out the links below for more info.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching/